# placeholder not working in python function

Tags: python

I have this function passing in two values in the param. the value page_url is not showing in the {page_url} but when I print(page_url) it shows up. Any idea?

```
def get_internal_links(soup, page_url):
    rtn_value = list()
    regex = re.compile(r'^((https:\/\/)?{page_url}\/|\/).+')
    links = soup.find_all('a', {'href': regex})
    for link in links:
        try:
            href = link['href']
            rtn_value.append(href)
        except AttributeError as e:
            pass
    return rtn_value
```

Comment: Add an `f` in front of the `r'^...`

Comment: what does that do ?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to construct your Regex pattern using the `page_url` variable (which I assume is a string), you will want to use the [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) notation. You can combine that with the raw-string notation like this:

```py
def get_internal_links(soup, page_url):
    rtn_value = list()
    regex = re.compile(fr'^((https:\/\/)?{page_url}\/|\/).+')
...
```